# Django Channel group assertion "__asgi_channel__" not in message

Tags: django

Any idea what causes this assertion when I tried to send a message through a django channel group?

"assert "**asgi_channel**" not in message"

```
from channels import Group

def ws_connect(message):
    Group("chatroom").add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})        

def ws_message(message):    
    Group('chatroom').send({"text": "aloha"})

def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chatroom").discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is already answered in somewhere else 
https://github.com/django/channels/issues/587

Solved it by upgrading these asgiref==1.1.1, asgi_redis==1.2.1 and asgi_ipc==1.3.1

Comment: Maybe it was but is nice to have it under StackOverflow. Thanks.